# Prevent any changes to currency formated cells in excel 2010

Tags: excel-2010

struggling to figure out if this is possible, long story short I have an excel template that is copied and renamed and then populated with data (trough an SSIS process). My question is is it possible to set the template cells so that only the format the cells is protected(currency, Date ect).

So for example - no matter what gets input, added, pasted etc the cell will always remain as a currency formatted cell?

Not been able to find a specific solution online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that i would go about this is writing a vba macro that runs after your data is populated that resets the specified cells back to the format that you want.